# Chat case assignment based on the previous case owner. Omnichannel

Tags: apex, service-cloud-console, omnichannel

To increase the experience of our chat users we would like to redirect always the same consumer to the same service agent (in case it is available and with capacity), doing that the consumer can engage with the agent in a better way. However, we can not find the way to do it....Do you know if there is any option to implement this behaviour?. Following the use case:

1. Consumer starts a chat session with a service agent
2. Consumer doesn't exist in Salesforce then Omnichannel routes the chat to one agent with the required skills
3. Consumer closes the chat
4. Consumer starts a new chat session with a service agent
5. Consumer exists in SF, therefore the chat is assigned to the last Service Agent who worked with him in the last case (*only if the service user is available and with capacity*)